# Variable containing login results from server application not returning expected value in a login system from an app

Tags: python, mysql, server, client

I have a simple loginGUI and logic where there is a server application connecting to a mySQl server and a Client application. The variable in the server script called message return some long undecodable string and is causing a UnicodeDecodeError when I user the function .decode(). However, I have no idea why the message variable is this and is not either "Login Successful!" or "Login failed!" Please Help. Thank you.

Here is the Server application:

```
import hashlib
import socket
import threading
import mysql.connector
import theGUI

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("localhost", 8888))

server.listen()


def handle_connection(c):
    c.send(theGUI.user_username.encode())
    username = c.recv(1024).decode()
    c.send(theGUI.user_password.encode())
    password = c.recv(1024)

    # Hash the password using SHA-256
    password = hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest()

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd='password',
        database="users",
        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
    )

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username = %s AND password = %s", (username, password))
    user = cur.fetchone()

    if user and user[1] == password:
        c.send("Login Successful!".encode())
    else:
        c.send("Login failed!".encode())




while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handle_connection, args=(client,)).start()
```

Here is the Login function with client connections application:

```
def login():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(("localhost", 3306))

    # Receive and send the username
    message = client.recv(1024)
    client.send(message)

    # Receive and send the password
    message = client.recv(1024)
    client.send(message)

    # Receive the login result
    result = client.recv(1024).decode()
    result_label.configure(text=result)
```

when I print the message variable its:
b'J\x00\x00\x00\n8.0.34\x00@\x01\x00\x00|r{\x01b\x18a\t\x00\xff\xff\xff\x02\x00\xff\xdf\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x06sA?dV\x1dif(G\x00caching_sha2_password\x00'

I think I must be missing something incredibly obvious.

Comment: You should be getting an error in your server app as it is failing to bind to port 3306 because MySQL is already bound to 3306. The response you are seeing in your client app is from MySQL, not your server app.

Comment: @user1191247 Thank you for the response it was very helpful. However, I changed the port on the server side but now when I run the program it is not responsive and crashes. I have no idea why.

Comment: In the client you have `client.send(message.encode())` but the message is already encoded. Just `client.send(message)`.

Comment: And now you have changed the port for the client back to `3306`. What are you tying to do? At the moment, when client connects to server, server sends `theGUI` values to the client which sends them straight back.